Twilio Incoming webhook for Whatsapp
I was working on whatsapp integration with an app. I've figured out outgoing messages statuses. I want to configure incoming messages from customer, but i couldn't found a way to put URL so that twilio request to that url.
Note that i'm currently on trial version of twilio. Did i have to upgrade my account? If yes, then where are docs so i can go through incoming message webhook.
Is this functionality restricted to paid users only?
Thanks,

To register the senders on Twilio, you do need to upgrade your account. They need to approve bundles and business addresses. After this process, you will be able to direct incoming messages to a webhook link within the sender's registration.
Here is the support documentation link:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/messaging-webhooks
